# PHP curl_exec doesn't contain url page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use curl to catch a web page and send it by email, but my `curl_exec($ch)` doesn't return anything. Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);

$resultat = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In this code, `$resultat` is empty... Do you guys know why? When I do a `phpinfo()`, I can see that curl is enabled.

**EDIT:**

Here is the `curl_getinfo($ch)` result:

```
Array
(
    [url] => ***link hidden***
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 358
    [request_size] => 93
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.005051
    [namelookup_time] => 0.001273
    [connect_time] => 0.001904
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.001931
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 904
    [speed_download] => 178974
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 904
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.00503
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array ()    
    [primary_ip] => (HIDDEN)
    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 192.168.145.80
    [local_port] => 37648
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: have you tried checking `curl_getinfo()` right after `curl_exec`?

Comment: Of course ! i forgot to show you, i Edit the main post

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, can you try curl_error($ch) and see if it says something usefull?

Comment: curl_error($ch) is empty too.. maybe the server where i work dont accept curl anymore, but the phpinfo() says that it does..

Comment: What does mean ”empty”? Most likely it is not *empty*, but something else, that you can see in the documentation...

Comment: well, i try to echo the $resultat or print_r(curl_error($ch)) and nothing happen

Comment: `var_dump` is usually best for debugging, as it tells the type in clearest format. Anyway, PHP does not have that kind of value that is “empty”, so you getting value of that type is impossible. What do you get returned?

Comment: the var_dump($resultat) shows: string(904)

Comment: I assume that means you got a string of length of 904 bytes, and you did not show rest of it? Then this question is invalid...

Comment: Why then, when I want to show the $resultat, i dont have anything in my page? I tried : "echo $resultat;" with no effect, blank page.. I'll edit the name of the question, I recognize that it's not valid anymore

Comment: Open the source of the page and look at the raw output of what the var_dump() outputted. It contains 904 bytes of data which we *can’t* know what it is about. And SO is not a debugger as a service, you need to do your work yourself.

Comment: Ok I understood, thanks (sorry i don't use var_dump so much) !
Well, it appears that CURL just got the code between the <head> balises of the page i want to use. It stops as soon as the <body> balise come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved because in my CURL page i didn't have the database connexion needed to generate the whole page. A little mistake :) Thanks for your answers.